# How to retrieve deleted photos (duplicate) from iphone?

Tags: iphone, photos.app

Recently i have imported my pics from iPhone in iPhoto and it asked me for deleting duplicate pics and i chose yes. But the problem is it has deleted some pics which i wanted but according to iPhoto they were duplicate.
So is there any way i can get those deleted photos back?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I end up using [Wonder Share](http://www.wondershare.net/ad/dr-fone/index.html?gclid=CPXbtZPhxLICFU0a6wodnV4AUg) (Mac)